# Filling in values in a blank data frame

Tags: r, reshape2

I have a data frame with a number of columns I read in, and now I want to add certain pieces **only to certain columns**.

For example, the variable `periodicnumber` exists in the dataframe called `df` and I want to give the first six rows the values 1 through 6. I thought code below would work but I get the error:

```
periodicnumber=seq(1,6)
df$periodicnumber=periodicnumber

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "periodicnumber", value = 1:6) : 
  replacement has 6 rows, data has 0
```

As in, were this in Excel, I would write the numbers 1 through 6 only on the `periodicnumber` column.

Comment: Why do you need to create a blank data.frame?  It is easier to do `df <- data.frame(periodicnumber)`

Comment: Does your “blank” data frame contain six rows? The error message suggests that there are no rows. In which case: why create an empty data frame at all (see akrun’s comment)?

Comment: I'll clarify this -- i'm importing a data frame with a bunch of columns.

Comment: Can you give us a sample of `df`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to change the **first** six rows of df, you need to specify that in the assignment:

```
periodicnumber=seq(1,6)    
df$periodicnumber[1:6]<-periodicnumber
```

More generally:

```
df$column[1:len(x)]<-x
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! I wasn't aware I had to actually specify the rows themselves.